# Google One Tap Javascript API/HTML API does not return nonce in JWT in Safari

Tags: safari, jwt, nonce, google-one-tap

When Google One Tap is implemented using Javascript API/HTML API including nonce, the returned JWT is missing nonce for Safari browser. Chrome and Fireforx returns the nonce as expected.

Please refer the code used.

```
const initializeGSI = () => {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: '132-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
      nonce: '7342364',
      callback: onOneTapSignedIn
    });
```

Browser Version
Safari Version 16.1 (18614.2.9.1.12)

Steps
Integrate Google One Tap using Javascript API/HTML API using a nonce.
Sign in via Google One Tap in Safari
Check retuned JWT

Using "itp_support" did not make any change on this.

This behaviour remains same for both Javascript API and HTML API.

When "Prevent cross-site tracking" is disabled at Safari, the nonce returns and works as expected. Safari has this default setting. Any workaround available other than changing the Safari's default behavior?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?